# How do I create a properly encoded multipart/form-data string in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a Hash of `string => string`, and `string => file` entries, how do I create a multipart/form-data string?

Comment: Not sure why would you do that on the server.. Or you are talking about encoding it on the frontend in js?

Comment: @kox it's what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing many questions like this in forums all over the web back up to 2008, I finally found the solution:

```
Rack::Test::Utils.build_multipart({foo: 'bar'}, true, true)
```

The first argument is for the data, the second to specify whether it's the first multipart and the last - and most important - is to force it to use multipart even for parameters that don't strictly require it (for example because there's no file upload happening).